# Passing Controller specific array to view

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, variables

**Requirement**

Iam creating number of forms with Laravel. So for my easy I am trying to implement a something like below where I hope this will help me to reduce my time.

1. Defining private variables . These variables are common to all functions in the controller
2. Pass default predefined array to all views in that controller

So this is how I tried to accomplish

```
  //defining default variables for the page. Just changing this variable will enough for this controller
private $titleForUpdations = 'University';
//Definig a default variable for the folder name. Just renaming this variable will affect all the  views
//making route with same folder name.  changing name at this place enough for this controller
private $folderName = 'universities';


public function commonArray(){
    //this array is common for all the function
    $array = [
        'mainTitle' => $this->titleForUpdations.' Management' ,
        'secondTitle' => 'Add New '.$this->titleForUpdations ,
        'add' => 'Add New '.$this->titleForUpdations ,
        'back' => 'Back to '.$this->titleForUpdations.' list',
        'detail' => $this->titleForUpdations.' Details',
        'pluralName' => $this->titleForUpdations.'ies' ];

    return $array;
}
```

Then I pass this `$array` to view as below

```
 public function index(University $model)
{
    //fetching all data from model and paginating it when passing to view
    return view('dboperations.'.$this->folderName.'.index', ['items' => $model->paginate(15) , $this-> commonArray()]);
}
```

Then I try to access those varibles in the view like below

```
@extends('layouts.app', ['title' => __($mainTitle)])

@section('content')
@include('users.partials.header', ['title' => __($secondTitle)])
```

But this continuously return the error **Undefined variable**

If I `dd($this->commonArray)` in a function it output what I wants as below.

```
array:6 [▼
  "mainTitle" => "University Management"
  "secondTitle" => "Add New University"
  "add" => "Add New University"
  "back" => "Back to University list"
  "detail" => "University Details"
  "pluralName" => "Universityies"
]
```

So could anyone please tell me is there is anything I missed?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed to add key name for your commonArray

```
return view('dboperations.'.$this->folderName.'.index', ['items' => $model->paginate(15) , 'commonArray' => $this-> commonArray()]);
```